# Flutter DevTools Treemap missing

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-management, devtools, flutter-devtools

The flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/devtools/memory) has a link to [this](https://medium.com/@fluttergems/mastering-dart-flutter-devtools-memory-view-part-7-of-8-e7f5aaf07e15) article. The article has a screenshot showing a treemap of object usage. The screen I see after following the instructions in the article differs considerably from the one shown in the article. I don't have `Analysis` and `Allocations` tabs and I can't find the treemap anywhere.

Article screenshot:

[image]

My screenshot.

[image]

I'm running the demo from the article in Windows VSCode.